# Is Lua an efficent gaming language?

Tags: game-design

Would Lua be a good language to learn? If you are looking to design games. I am not sure if it would be useful to learn it.

Comment: It's a decent language if you can live with its quirks. https://love2d.org/

Comment: I'm using Love2d lua based game engine, and I find it enjoyable